# The expression references the parameter , which does not exist in the Parameters collection. (rsRuntimeErrorInExpression)

Tags: reporting-services

I searched for this exception and found that this happens when dependent parameters are not added in the correct order in your ReportData parameters collection.

But this is not the case and my parameters are in the correct order.

I have four parameters and two datasets, first dataset uses all the four parameters and is working fine and not throwing any error.

While the other dataset is using using only one parameter which is the fourth parameter in the parameter list. This dataset is throwing this exception.

The very wierd thing is if I use first or second parameter in my dataset-2 it works fine but as soon as I use parameter after second one (third and fourth) it starts throwing this exception. While the Dataset-1 is already using all the parameters without any problem.

I have tried all the combinations and all the possible changes like adding new parameter etc. but nothing is working.

Any idea of this strange behavior?

**Edit**

Parameters

- DateFrom
- DateTo
- Year
- UserName
- PersonnelNumber

Datasets

- Dataset-1
- Dataset-2

`PersonnelNumber` parameter is dependent on `UserName` parameter and so they are in correct order. `UserName` returns built-in function User-Id

`Dataset-1` is using all the parameters and working fine.

`Dataset-2` works fine only till I use parameters `DateFrom` and `DateTo` and starts throwing exception if I use any parameter after that, that is `Year` and `PersonnelNumber`

Quite wierd!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the issue.

Actually the parameter `Year` is dependent on the value of `Dataset-2` and the dataset calculates its values using parameter `PersonnelNumber`, so indirectly parameter `Year` is dependent on parameter `PersonnelNumber`.

When I changed the order and added parameter `Year` after `PersonnelNumber` it finally worked!! :)